# A simple version of Haskell's map

Tags: haskell, dictionary, ghci

I'm trying to define map in ghci recursively. What I've come up with so far is the following:

```
let mymap f (x:xs) = if null xs then [] else f x : map f xs
```

What I'd like to do now is to simplify it a bit  and hardcode the list inside the code, i.e., write a map function which takes a function as argument and does what the real map does but only to a specific list e.g., [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. 
Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Sure.  It's just `mymap f = [f 1, f 2, f 3, f 4, f 5]`.  This is pointless, however.

Comment: @TomEllis I'd do that as `mymap f = map f [1..5]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your map function isn't entirely correct.  If I were to input `mymap (+1) [1]`, I would expect to get `[2]` back, but instead I'd get `[]`.  If I tried `mymap (+1) []`, my program would crash on a pattern match failure, since you haven't defined that case.  Instead, consider defining your `mymap` as

```
mymap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mymap f [] = []
mymap f (x:xs) = f x : mymap f xs
```

If you want to do it inline with an if statement then you'd have to do

```
mymap f xs = if null xs then [] else f (head xs) : mymap f (tail xs)
```

These do essentially the same thing, but the first is a bit easier to read in my opinion.

---

If you want to use `mymap` to define a function that maps only over a specific list, you could do so pretty easily as

```
mapOnMyList :: (Int -> b) -> [b]
mapOnMyList f = mymap f [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or in point-free form

```
mapOnMyList = (`mymap` [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

using `mymap` as an infix operator.  This is equivalent to `flip mymap [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, but the operator form is usually preferred since `flip` is not necessarily free to execute.

---

You can also do this using list comprehensions:

```
mymap f xs = [f x | x <- xs]
```

Or if you want to hard code the list

```
mapOnMyList f = [f x | x <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Personally, I find `flip` much more readable than infix operators, but that's just taste, I guess.

Comment: Actually I'd like to have my initial inline definition (or yours which is more correct) and hard code the list inside the code but without touching the rest of the code.

Comment: @Mephy I agree that it's more readable, but `flip` is not inlined, so if your usage is in an inner loop then you could suffer a performance penalty.  GHC may be able to optimize this away, but the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#flip) doesn't give any indication that it does.

Comment: @SotirisKal I'm not sure I understand what you're wanting to do.  Do you want the list inside the definition of `mymap` without having to write an additional function?

Comment: Apologies if I haven't explained it clearly. I just want to write an inline map which only takes one argument, i.e., the function f. For instance: let mymap f = "hardcode here the list, do what the original map does but without calling it and return the result."

Comment: Why not just `mymap f = [f x | x <- hardcodedList]`?

Comment: @SotirisKal. Or you can use `mymap f = go f hardcodedList where go g xs = <some implementation from above>`

Comment: I feel that mymap f = [f x | x <- hardcodedList] does the trick. But can you please give an example? Could such a thing be written with an if? I know it sounds weird but it's for educational purposes. Not a homework.

Comment: @SotirisKal. Good for stretching your understanding. Generally I'd advise that hardcoding things in leads to pretty messy code.

Comment: Why wouldn't flip be inlined? I think relative readability depends on context, but here I'd go with flip.

Comment: I believe `flip` *will* be inlined whenever GHC thinks that makes sense. `INLINE` and `INLINABLE`, I believe, are only required for functions that GHC thinks are too big to be likely candidates for inlining. `flip` is *tiny*. You'd have to look over the Core to be sure, of course.

Comment: @dfeuer I tried a simple test for `flip (+) 1 2`, but as it turns out the optimizer turns this into `3` anyway.  It does look like GHC can optimize this without a special rule for it, but these are the sorts of things that I'm always wary of.  I don't want to assume that GHC is going to optimize something for me without looking at core first.

Comment: bheklir's answer does what I want. However, I'm still curious whether the same result could be achieved using map recursively.

Comment: `let yourMap = (flip ((flip id) [] (flip foldr)) [1..10]) . ((:) .)`
This is a little bit more recursiony than the list comprehension (with \infty% more folds), still inline, pointfree, and you can replace [1..10] with whatever you want. Enjoy your new map.

Comment: My only regret is that I couldn't apply flip to the `(.)`'s.

Comment: @genisage You can get at least one more `flip` in there: `let yourMap = flip (.) ((.) (:)) (flip ((flip id) [] (flip foldr)) [1..10])`